Matplotlib canvas has no buffer_rgba attribute
I use the manim-matplotlib technique for animating my plots. On the PC that I am running this on I use a virtual environment. From one day to the other this stopped working and I am wondering why. Matplotlib 3.7.5, Python 3.8
def figtoimg(fig):
    fig.canvas.draw()
    img = fig.canvas.buffer_rgba()
    plt.close(fig)
    return img

Using the function above throws the following error:
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasPgf' object has no attribute 'buffer_rgba'


I don't get that error when I run your code with Matplotlib 3.7.5.

Only raster graphics backends (e.g. Agg backends) have a buffer_rgba. Vector graphics backends as your PGF backend done have a rgba buffer. See here for details about backends.

Uhh, I understand. Now that you mention it, I realize that elsewhere, I have set the backend to pgf for a different plot. To fix it I now store the backend before changing it to pgf and reset it afterwards. Thanks.
